# Running Laravel project on XAMPP:" NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 179"

Tags: php, laravel, exception, routes, xampp

I'm using XAMPP to run my Laravel project, and it runs on "`localhost/myproject/public`" but when I click on the login link I get this error:

> NotFoundHttpException
>   in RouteCollection.php line 179

But the strange thing is that, when I run the project on my Windows CMD using `"php artisan serve"` and then go to my browser and type `"http://127.0.0.1:8000"` my project works fully and I don't get any error.

What am I doing wrong with XAMPP? How can I get to run my project properly using XAMPP?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: laravel has entry point in `public` folder so you need to point it in xammp, so that apache will treat `public` directory as root

Comment: Thanks for replying!
And I'm sorry but I'm kinda newbie with XAMPP. So in other words.. how can I do that?

Comment: Can you please add your XAMPP virtual host configuration?